# Calculating start and end index from a column of text in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I'm making a code which will fetch the start and end index of a text in VBA.
This condition when applied to cell should change accordingly

This is a code for counting length of words, but got stuck in the index part,
the output of my StartIndex function is always 0. I want to make one more EndIndex function

```
Public Function CountWords(ByVal strText As String) As Long
    Application.Volatile
    CountWords = UBound(Split(strText, " ")) + 1
End Function

Length = 1
StartIndex = 0

Public Function StartIndex(ByVal strText As String) As Long
    Application.Volatile
    StartIndex = Length + StartIndex
    Length = UBound(Split(strText, " ")) + 1
End Function
```

consider the example, I have **col 1** and want to generate **startIndex** and **endIndex**

```
          Col1                          startIndex               endIndex
VBA Index Printer Friendly version         1                        5
 Adobe Acrobat version                     6                        8
A UDF can remain in a code module          9                       15
```

Comment: You can't have statements like `Length = 1` outside of a method.

Comment: Do you want 1 and 3 in the 2nd row? Similarly do you want 1 and 8 in the 3rd row?

Comment: no, see the col1 , startIndex, endIndex ...it shows the index position of each word which should keep on updating based on previous cell

Comment: Then it should be 16 and not 15 for the last one?

Comment: yes ok 16, but do you know how may i do it ? I'm really stuck on it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this result using a simple setup as below. Assuming data starts in from Cell A3.

In cell B3 insert hard coded value: `1`

In cell B4 insert formula         : `=C3+1`

In cell C3 insert formula         : `=B3+(LEN($A3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A3," ","")))`

Copy down the formulas in cell B4 and C3 till the last row of your data in column A.

Comment: in my case is B3 my startIndex column? C2 my end index column? what is B2 ?

Comment: Note: I have the text data by default, just need to generate start and end indexes

Comment: @andro I have edited my response. Try to follow the steps and check results.

Comment: instead of writing formula and performing operation, can't we convert this into a VGA function

Comment: ++ I had the same answer in the draft... ready to post... LOL

Comment: @andro that may not be really efficient when native functions can do the job. Choice is totally up to you.